# Jenkins and MSBuild on a Mac

Tags: .net, macos, xamarin, jenkins, msbuild

I am trying to setup a CI server on a Mac using Jenkins. It will be eventually be building Xamarin solutions. Currently I have it checking code out from our svn server, doing a restore for the Nuget packages, and finally trying to build the projects.

I currently am testing this on a Xamarin .NET 2.0 standard library. The checkout and restore work but on the build step I get errors saying I am missing references to Mscorlib amongst other things. I can build the project in Visual Studio on Mac just fine. What am I doing wrong with the setup?

I have the Jenkins MSBuild plugin setup to run msbuild from /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/msbuild. Below is the console output from Jenkins:

```
    Started by user admin
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out https://svn.MyComp.net/svn/MyProj/MyProjMobile/MyProjMobile/MyProjMobile at revision '2018-04-05T13:45:47.739 -0700' --quiet
Using sole credentials MyUsername/****** in realm ‘<https://svn.MyComp.net:443> VisualSVN Server’
At revision 62

No changes for https://svn.MyComp.net/svn/MyProj/MyProjMobile/MyProjMobile/MyProjMobile since the previous build
Path To MSBuild.exe: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/msbuild
FATAL: Unable to use this plugin on this kind of operation system
Executing the command /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/msbuild /t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:RestoreSources=http://192.168.102.158/MyCompNuget/nuget%3Bhttps://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj from /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin
[MyProjMobile.Xamarin] $ /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/msbuild /t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:RestoreSources=http://192.168.102.158/MyCompNuget/nuget%3Bhttps://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.0.0 (xplat-master/67e8006d Thu Mar  8 17:15:24 EST 2018) for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/5/2018 1:45:51 PM.
Project "/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj" on node 1 (restore;build target(s)).
Restore:
  Restoring packages for /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj...
  Committing restore...
  Generating MSBuild file /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/obj/MyProjMobile.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/obj/MyProjMobile.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/obj/project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 855.8 ms for /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      /Users/MyComp/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      http://192.168.102.158/MyCompNuget/nuget
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin/Release/netstandard2.0/".
  Creating directory "obj/Release/netstandard2.0/".
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.8.1/lib/mono/4.5/csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705,1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETSTANDARD2_0 /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/bcrypt.net-next/2.1.3/lib/netstandard2.0/BCrypt.Net-Next.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/MyComp.encryptionservice/1.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/EncryptionService.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/freshmvvm/2.2.4/lib/netstandard1.0/FreshIOC.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/freshmvvm/2.2.4/lib/netstandard1.0/FreshMvvm.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/microsoft.csharp/4.0.1/ref/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/microsoft.win32.primitives/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/modernhttpclient-updated/2.6.1/lib/netstandard2.0/ModernHttpClient.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/newtonsoft.json/9.0.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/pclcrypto/2.1.17-alpha-g5b1e8dff8c/lib/netstandard1.0/pclcrypto.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/pinvoke.kernel32/0.5.126/lib/netstandard1.1/PInvoke.Kernel32.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/pinvoke.windows.core/0.5.126/lib/netstandard1.1/PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.4.118/lib/netstandard1.1/SQLite-net.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/MyComp.sqlite.net.cipher.std/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/SQLite.Net.Cipher.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/MyComp.sqlitenetextensions.std/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/MyComp.sqlitenetextensionsasync.std/1.0.0/lib/netstandard1.3/SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/1.1.9/lib/netstandard1.1/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.bundle_green/1.1.9/lib/netstandard1.1/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/sqlitepclraw.core/1.1.9/lib/netstandard1.1/SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.appcontext/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.AppContext.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.collections.concurrent/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.collections/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Collections.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.console/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Console.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.debug/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.tools/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.0/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.tracing/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.dynamic.runtime/4.0.11/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.globalization.calendars/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Globalization.Calendars.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.globalization/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Globalization.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.io.compression/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.IO.Compression.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.io.compression.zipfile/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.io/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.IO.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.io.filesystem/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.IO.FileSystem.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.io.filesystem.primitives/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.linq/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.Linq.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.linq.expressions/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.net.http/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.net.primitives/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.net.sockets/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Net.Sockets.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.objectmodel/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.reflection/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Reflection.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.reflection.extensions/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.0/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.reflection.primitives/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.0/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.resources.resourcemanager/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.0/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.extensions/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.handles/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.interopservices/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.1/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.numerics/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.1/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.primitives/4.1.1/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.security.cryptography.algorithms/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.security.cryptography.encoding/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.security.cryptography.primitives/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.4/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.text.encoding/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.text.encoding.extensions/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.text.regularexpressions/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.6/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.threading/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Threading.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.threading.tasks/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.threading.timer/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.2/System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.xml.readerwriter/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/system.xml.xdocument/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/validation/2.4.18/lib/netstandard1.3/Validation.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/xamarin.auth/1.6.0.1/lib/netstandard1.6/Xamarin.Auth.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/2.5.0.280555/lib/netstandard1.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/2.5.0.280555/lib/netstandard1.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll /reference:/Users/MyComp/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/2.5.0.280555/lib/netstandard1.0/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /nologo /optimize+ /out:obj/Release/netstandard2.0/MyProjMobile.dll /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ App.xaml.cs Auth/AuthCompletedEvent.cs Auth/AuthenticationState.cs Auth/AuthErrorEvent.cs Auth/AuthExtensions.cs Auth/Constants.cs Auth/MyCompOAuth2Authenticator.cs Data/MyProjUser.cs Data/GoogleUser.cs Data/Grade.cs Data/Role.cs Data/SampleUser.cs Database/AsyncDatabase.cs Database/Database.cs Database/DependencyServiceWrapper.cs Database/IDependencyService.cs Database/ISqLite.cs Model/BaseModel.cs Page/LoginPage.xaml.cs ServicePointConfiguration.cs SSLHttpClient.cs ViewModel/Page/LoginPageViewModel.cs ViewModel/PageModelMapper.cs "/var/folders/dj/zhmtcqbn60xccl1b1lghkdcr0000gn/T/.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj/Release/netstandard2.0/MyProjMobile.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
App.xaml.cs(35,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
Page/LoginPage.xaml.cs(17,4): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
ServicePointConfiguration.cs(17,13): error CS0103: The name 'ServicePointManager' does not exist in the current context [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
ServicePointConfiguration.cs(17,52): error CS0103: The name 'SecurityProtocolType' does not exist in the current context [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
ServicePointConfiguration.cs(18,13): error CS0103: The name 'ServicePointManager' does not exist in the current context [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
SSLHttpClient.cs(9,68): error CS0012: The type 'HttpClientHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
SSLHttpClient.cs(9,73): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler' [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
ServicePointConfiguration.cs(37,61): error CS1061: 'X509Certificate' does not contain a definition for 'GetPublicKeyString' and no extension method 'GetPublicKeyString' accepting a first argument of type 'X509Certificate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
SSLHttpClient.cs(15,74): error CS0012: The type 'HttpClientHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
SSLHttpClient.cs(15,74): error CS0117: 'NativeMessageHandler' does not contain a definition for 'Credentials' [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
SSLHttpClient.cs(15,13): error CS0012: The type 'HttpClientHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj]
Done Building Project "/Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj" (restore;build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Did you update all of your nuget packages to the same version in your solution? You appear to have a lot of conflicts. It's good to fix the noise since sometimes it causes other issues.

Comment: Unfortunately these are all the latest versions of each nuget package. While there are a lot of conflicts, everything is building fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: This error `'BCrypt.Net-PCL 1.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`, it looks like you are restoring the incorrect version for your project.  Can you change MyProjMobile.csproj to run in .Net 4.6.1?

Comment: Thanks for the help @AlwaysLearning, I have gone through the dependencies and have found some newer nuget packages that target .net standard that were unpublished in the store. I also went through for the couple I could not find, downloaded their souce code and made changes to target .net standard. I have removed all those warnings. I still get errors, some the same, some different. Please see first post with updated build log output.

Comment: did you see this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/jenkins-walkthrough Important section being "The MSBuild plugin must be configured to use /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild to compile Visual Studio for Mac solution and project files. Scroll down the Configure System [Jenkins] page until the Add MSBuild button appears, as shown in the screenshot below:" Can you confirm you have an installation available?

Comment: Yes I did. I originally tried xbuild but get a message saying its deprecated and to use msbuild instead. I can build another xamarin project (a small class library fine which is actually a dependency of the larger project that is failing). All the same settings as far as Jenkins goes.

Comment: Maybe your xbuild plugin is out of date? According to the documentation I sent in the last comment, looks like your path should point here "
while the Path to MSBuild should be the path to xbuild, which is typically /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild" . However your path is different. When you change the path to the above, does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't. Complains it's not in the MSBuild format. I'm pretty sure that page is out of date. Even Visual Studio on mac has a default option selected to use MSBuild instead of XBuild.

Comment: App.xaml.cs, right-click and check the file properties "Build Action" and change it to "Embedded Resource" if it isn't that already. Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: No change. This builds fine on the same mac in Visual Studio.

Comment: No change to the build output? If not, let's do this; execute msbuild from the mac equivalent on the command prompt on the same machine you do the Visual Studio build. msbuild and visual studio build actually behave differently which is why it might work in visual studio but not on msbuild. Add to that executing via jenkins and that's another level of difference. Let's see if you can do msbuild using the same flags/switches that you use in Jenkins and have it work locally so we can rule that out.

Comment: Similar to this, but on your local machine. You'll need to find the path to your msbuild locally and potentially play with this in case there are special switches for jenkins:
/t:restore /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:RestoreSources=http://192.168.102.158/MyCompNuget/nuget%3Bhttps://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin/MyProjMobile.csproj from /Users/MyComp/.jenkins/workspace/MyProjMobile.Xamarin

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, did you find a way to resolve your issue?

Comment: I believe the following line fixed it in the csproj file:<NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>2.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<!--<AssetTargetFallback>net461</AssetTargetFallback>-->
<NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>2.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
<Configurations>Debug;Release;Jenkins</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
```